# Warning: Cannot modify header.. ayuda

Tags: php

No se porque me sale el siguiente error. A ver si me ayudan. Esto sucede cuando presiono el boton. Entrar.

**Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..**

El tema es que me funciona perfecto en local, pero al subirlo al servidor me arroja este error online.

```
require ("modulos/head.php");


<body>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['entrar'])) {

        try{

            $base= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=prueba', 'root', '');

            $base->setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email= :email AND password= :password";

            $resultado=$base->prepare ($sql);

            $login=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['email']));
            $password=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['password']));

            $resultado->bindValue(':email', $login);
            $resultado->bindValue(':password', $password);

            $resultado->execute();

            $numero_registro=$resultado->rowCount();

            if($numero_registro!=0) {

                header ('Location: panel.php');

            } else {

                header ('Location: index.php');

            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            die ("Error: " . $e->getMessage ());
        }

    }

    ?>
    <h1>CONSORCISTAS</h1>
    <div class="seccionlog">
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" class="login">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
            <input type="text" name="password" id="clave" placeholder="Clave"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="entrar" id="entrar" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-link">
            <p>No tienes una cuenta?</p>
            <a href="registro.php">Registrate ahora!</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede darse porque envías un header, pero el analizador de php continúa con el resto del script, lo que provocaría que se envíe el header después de renderizar como tal la página, se me ocurre que puedes intentar añadir un exit o un die bajo el llamado al header, así obligas a que se finalice el script.

```
header('Location: panel.php');
exit();
```

o

```
header('Location: panel.php');
die;
```

Comment: Hola Henry! no, ninguno de los dos funcionó. Sigue tirando el mismo error. Lo curioso es que en localhost me funciona perfecto. El problema aparecio cuando lo lleve online.

Comment: Es extraño, has revisado que el archivo de configuración php.ini de los dos servidores estén configurados de manera similar?

Comment: No, pero lo estare mirando. muchas gracias!!

Comment: Lo que hice fue agregar echo "<script>window.location='xx.php'; </script>"; en lugar de los headers location. y funciona. Pero la pregunta es, porque los headers estan funcionando en local pero en el servidor no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Una recomendación es que pongas todos los tags html después del código php en el que se setea el header:

```
<?php
....
 if($numero_registro!=0) {
    header ('Location: panel.php');
 } else {
    header ('Location: index.php');
 }
...
?>
<html>
<header>
...
</header>
<body>
...
<?php ... ?>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Luego de esto verifica que el servidor no esté generando mensajes de warning o errores que pudiesen estarse enviando antes que se configure el header. Esto lo puedes configurar en el `php.ini` en la sección `reporting level`.

La idea es que si el servidor genera texto antes del seteo de los headers, estos ya no pueden ser seteados. Los headers deben configurarse antes de que cualquier texto sea enviado por el servidor.

Comment: Byron voy a observar todo esto muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Byron, no funciona tampoco. El problema esta con los header location.

Comment: Revisando las herramientas de desarrollador del browser, qué contenido te está devolviendo el servidor y qué tienen los headers?